# How to display Option menu on MapView when user presses "menu" button

Tags: android, android-mapview

I have created a sample Google Map application.

In that, I want to display an Option menu on map (mapview) within the same activity when user presses the "menu" button.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this through the same way you add an options menu for a basic activity.
Refer to this link if you want to know the way option menus are added.
http://www.droidnova.com/how-to-create-an-option-menu,427.html

Comment: captain: Error 404 - Not Found